# How to parse a specific table using Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to pull the Name, Weight, and Shares Held table in the Holdings tab of this page: https://www.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=DIA

```ruby
# get table headers
headers = []
page.xpath('//*/table/thead/tr/th').each do |th|
  headers << th.text
end

# get table rows
rows = []
page.xpath('//*/table/tbody/tr').each_with_index do |row, i|
  rows[i] = {}
  row.xpath('td').each_with_index do |td, j|
    rows[i][headers[j]] = td.text
  end
end
puts page.xpath("//table//tr//td[1]/text()")
p rows
```

This is the code I have right now, and I'm not entirely sure how to do the xpath. The `puts page.xpath("//table//tr//td[1]/text()")` call returns all the labels for all the tables, but I only want the ones with the company names. How do I only choose that specific table's information, and how do I rewrite the loop to pull from that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". You need to supply the _minimal_ input that demonstrates the problem. That means, the HTML you're working with needs to be reduced to the bare minimum and then added to the question. Don't expect us to write code that retrieves that page, or that we'll reduce it for you just to help you. You have to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it to use css selectors

```
rows = doc.css("div#FUND_TOP_HOLDINGS td").map(&:text).each_slice(3).to_a
```